# raster::plot() plotting raster too small- is there an alternative on ggplot?

Tags: raster, r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot this [raster](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1yxkn17y7cplchs/MOD13Q1_2000-02-18.250m_16_days_NDVI.tif?dl=0) on R. The object is quite big, but when plotting it using the `raster::plot()` function, I obtain a very tiny image, as attached.

The code I use to produce it is the following:

```
r <- raster::raster("MOD13Q1_2000-02-18.250m_16_days_NDVI.tif")
r <- setMinMax(r)
raster::plot(r)
```

I tried to set `xlim` limits, with no success. I then tried to move to `ggplot2`, as an alternative (following [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227182/how-to-set-use-ggplot2-to-map-a-raster)), but I obtain the following

```
ggplot(r) + geom_tile(aes(fill=value))
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class RasterLayer
```

I found around that, to plot raster objects with `ggplot()`, I should first convert it into a `data.frame`. However, as my object is quite big (about 55million obs.), that would be very inefficient. I am then stuck on what to do. Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The base plot method works fine for me:

[image]

so I suspect something has gone amiss with your graphics device. If using `rstudio`, I think there's a little button to reset the graphics window, otherwise try `dev.off()` to switch the graphics window off, and the next `plot` will create a new one.

This behaviour generally happens when a previous graphics operation has left the graphics device in a non-default state, such as having divided it up to put a legend in a section of window. A reset as described above usually helps.

There's no need to look to `ggplot` - the `raster` package plot methods are very well optimised for big rasters and will sample down large rasters for speed.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. For some reason it still does not work, and clearly there is a problem with my graphic device. I tried other rasters from tutorials on the web and I am having the same issue. My issue is not with the picture, then, but with some setup on my plotting device. Any thoughts on how to fix that?

Comment: Edit your question and give some more info on your system, including operating system, R version, raster version etc. If you restart R and do `plot(raster::raster(matrix(1:100,10,10)))` does it still fail?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Spacedman answer... Sometimes, some packages change plot parameters.

You need to set back default parameters and plot again:

```
r <- raster::raster("MOD13Q1_2000-02-18.250m_16_days_NDVI.tif")

par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1), mgp = c(3, 1, 0), mfrow = c(1,1), las = 0)

plot(r)
```

You can also include this into `plot` function to override an unexpect behaivour:

```
r <- raster::raster("MOD13Q1_2000-02-18.250m_16_days_NDVI.tif")

plot(r,mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1), mgp = c(3, 1, 0), mfrow = c(1,1), las = 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your message. It still does not work. I am facing this problem with other tif files, as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using RStudio?

Comment: Yes I am, and indeed I guess that is the problem. I manage to plot it on R, or even running R through the Terminal (I am using a mac). I guess I will open a new question as this one has somehow lost sense...

Comment: I also work with RStudio on macOS. Maybe plot window is too small, try resizing borders

Comment: Resizing borders did not work at the end. The issue was some changes made by the `rts` package I installed - I have already contacted its developer. Interestingly, plotting with `rastervis::levelplot()` works fine.

Comment: Interesting. I've worked with `rts` package before without problems. Maybe need to set xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax inside `plot()` settings