# RStudio's Graphic Device plotting rasters too tiny?

Tags: raster, r

I am having some issues when plotting rasters with the `raster::plot` function. It seems that my Rstudio's graphic device has some problem and the plots are just very very tiny. As of illustration, if the outcome of

```
raster::plot(raster::raster(matrix(1:100,10,10)))
```

is

[image]

whereas if plotting it on R application or through my Mac's terminal, the output is just perfect. This happens to any raster I try to plot. In both applications, my `raster` and `sp` packages version are the same (2.6-7 and 1.2-5, respectively).

I am running RStudio version 1.0.136 on a 64bit iMac (late 2015). The R version running is 3.3.2. My os is version 10.12.6 (macOS Sierra). Any thoughts?

This question follows up [raster::plot() plotting raster too small- is there an alternative on ggplot?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265208), where I thought the issue was the raster file.

Comment: Upgrade to R 3.4.x and the latest RStudio and try again

Comment: It actually did not work. Moreover, it happens to happen only in RStudio. Running the same code from R or from the Terminal, the plot comes out perfectly. Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like Rstudio weirdness.... try http://community.rstudio.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by updating R AND by clicking on the Clear all Plots sign (a broom) in the plot window.